# GridView and custom child View - how to setup the layout params

Tags: java, android, layout, gridview

I want to have GridView with custom view. The custom view is simply RelativeLayout wirg 2 ImageViews. I want that there is no vertical and horizontal spacing between items and the GridLayout has 4 columns when screen orientation is vertical and 7 columns when orientation is horizontal. Of course I want the child views to adjust their sizes in order to fullfill the above requirements.
How to define the layout xmls?